# Python Sqlite3: Create a schema without having to use a second database

Tags: python, database, sqlite

I would like to create a schema for a sqlite3 database in python, but sqlite does not appear to support `CREATE SCHEMA` ([sqlite docs](https://www.sqlite.org/lang.html)). I've looked into `ATTACH`, and it seems like it would do the job by using a second database but I only need one database that has a schema.

I would like to do something along these lines:

```
import sqlite3
db = sqlite3.connect('db_file.db')
db.execute("CREATE TABLE my_schema.my_table(column TYPE);")
db.commit()
```

However, it throws an exception:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Mod/Projects/sandbox/test_db.py", line 8, in <module>
    db.execute("CREATE TABLE my_schema.my_table(column TYPE);")
OperationalError: unknown database my_schema
```

I know I can use `ATTACH` like so...

```
import sqlite3
db = sqlite3.connect('db_file.db')
db.execute("ATTACH DATABASE 'db_file_2.db' AS 'my_schema';")
db.execute("CREATE TABLE my_schema.my_table(column TYPE);")
db.commit()
```

...but is there any way to create a schema without a second database?

Comment: Why do you need a schema at all then? Why not just use `CREATE TABLE my_table(column TYPE);` instead?

Comment: In any case, the main database uses the schema name `main`.

Comment: Sorry, I should've clarified in my original post. I have to use the same INSERT queries from a MySQL database. The sqlite3 database is created if the mysql db connection fails in any way.

Comment: I managed to keep similar SQLAlchemy code between PostgreSQL and SQLite, by setting the SQLite schema to `main`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The main database is always named `main`, you cannot change that name.

You *can* just create an in-memory database and attach your database to that using an arbitrary name:

```
conn = sqlite3.connect(':memory:')
conn.execute("attach ? as 'schemaname'", (filename,))
```

However, if you are going to be using the database as a fallback for a main MySQL database, I urge you to look in to [SQLAlchemy](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/) to handle the database abstraction here and let it worry about generating the correct SQL for either MySQL or SQLite.

Comment: Will the data be saved to the attached database file? I will look into SQLAlchemy, but my supervisor has been using [pyodbc](https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc) so I've been trying to use the same tools and packages he already has in place.

Comment: @JohnSmithy: yes, inserts would go to the right database, provided you use the qualified name. SQLAlchemy can work with pyodbc connections.

Comment: Awesome, that's what i needed to know. If i could upvote you i would! Thanks for your help!!

Answer (score 18):

In our project, we are using Postgresql as the production database with separate schemas for each service.
I wanted to use Sqlite3 for unit testing. So I needed a way to create a schema.

The [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30897522) helped me figure out the solution.
I use [SQLAlchemy](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/) in my project (in Flask along with [Flask-SQLAlchemy](http://flask-sqlalchemy.pocoo.org/2.1/)).

I want to share how I did it here in the hope that it may help someone.

Suppose I am using in-memory database, and the schema I want to use is
`my_schema`. The commands would look like the following:

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

eng = create_engine("sqlite://")
conn = eng.connect()
conn.execute("attach ':memory:' as my_schema")
```

You could find more information about SQLite usage in SQLAlchemy at: http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/dialects/sqlite.html

In case you are using Flask-SQLAlchemy, you could do the same as the above example in the following way:

```
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = 'sqlite://'

db = SQLAlchemy()
# Create Flask app object, attach it to db object, and then do:
with app.app_context():
    with db.engine.connect() as con:
        con.execute("attach ':memory:' as svc_kpi")
```

Answer (score 0):

When trying to follow the accepted answer, I was running into issue `sqlalchemy.exc.ObjectNotExecutableError: Not an executable object: "attach ':memory:' as party_master"`

To solve this I had to do this:

```py
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

engine = create_engine("sqlite://")
connection = engine.raw_connection()
try:
    # Get a SQLite cursor from the connection
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    # Execute the ATTACH DATABASE command
    cursor.execute("ATTACH DATABASE ':memory:' AS party_master")
    # Commit the transaction
    connection.commit()
finally:
    # Close the connection
    connection.close()
```