# Does SQLite support schemas (i.e., in the Postgres sense of the word)?

Tags: sqlite, schema

This is a tough one to search for. I searched for `SQLite schema` (obviously not good), `SQLite namespace`, and `SQLite named database`, but came up empty. Basically, I have a bunch of different tables named info, and in Postgres each of the tables is in a separate schema (e.g., `student.info`, `teacher.info`, etc). I'm just wondering if SQLite has something similar to Postgres schemas.

Comment: dupe: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33960762/does-sqlite-support-multiple-schematas-within-the-same-database , related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30897377/python-sqlite3-create-a-schema-without-having-to-use-a-second-database

Answer (score 7, accepted):

SQLite uses schema names to to access objects in [attached](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_attach.html) databases.

So in SQLite, you should use schema names only when you already have multiple database files for some reason.
Using multiple databases to emulate PostgreSQL-style schemas might be possible, but is usually a bad idea. (And there are many other differences in their SQL dialects.)